# Xcode 8.1 - NSManagedObjectContext missing in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmanagedobjectcontext

today im working with a new project created in Xcode 8.1 where i want to use CoreData.

With Xcode 7 there was automatically a NSManagedObjectContext Object in the AppDelegate Class, but in Xcode 8.1 this object is missing.

The NSPersistentStoreCoordinator was changed to NSPersistentContainer.

Now i have no clue how to access the NSManagedObjectContext to write and read values in/from CoreData.

In projects created with Xcode 7 that was the way i've done:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSManagedObject *newEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Someone has a solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
```

Next time i have to read the documentation twice.

Comment: Hi, Can you add link to documentation for future reference? This answer is really helpful.

Comment: Hey, im sorry i don't now in what kind of documentation i found the solution, but here is the link to the NSPersistentContainer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer?language=objc but i'm glad it helped you.